# Network Latency between GCP server and linux data centres

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn

What are the best practices to avoid network latency between GCP server and unix server. My client application, which is on linux, is accessing GCP end point, but facing network latency. How to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suspecting that part of the latency is not due to the distance between your server and GCP? If not then obviously all you can do is (1) place your server closer to your GCP node and (2) maybe cluster/parallelize your GCP requests if you have many of them.

So I suggest that you determine the distance between the two sites and compare it to the roundtrip time for your requests. If it's significantly larger then indeed you will have to analyze the structure of your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Latency is not related to the OS you are using. [Network latency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency) is a measure of the time delay required for information to travel across a network. In all the factors that may affect this time delay, the one you can manage in cloud is the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_performance#Latency) from the source to the destination. You can find other latency factors in this [previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/129386/factors-affecting-network-latency).

If you are looking to [optimize the latency](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/optimize-app-latency) you could use a Cloud Load Balancer. Using [Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), the requests are always routed to the instance group that is closest to the user. With load balancer you can also use [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/). Cloud CDN reduces latency by serving assets directly at Google's network edge.